How does Paul’s use of 'dead' in Ephesians 2:1 compared to his use of the same term in Romans 6:11 ('dead to sin') and Romans 7:9 ('I died')?
Does the term 'dead' (Ephesians 2:1) imply total spiritual incapacitation of our spirit, or does it refer to our spirit’s inability to respond to God?
Text: (NET)

And although you were dead in your transgressions and sins - Ephesians
2:1
So you too consider yourselves dead to sin, but alive to God in Christ
Jesus - Romans 6:11
And I was once alive apart from the law, but with the coming of the
commandment sin became alive and I died - Romans 7:9-10a)


Not so fast - different Greek words are involved in these four texts:

Eph 2:1 - νεκρός (nekros) = "dead, lifeless" an adjective
Rom 6:11 - νεκρός (nekros) = "dead, lifeless" an adjective
Rom 7:9 - ἀποθνῄσκω (apothnéskó) = "I died" a verb.
Rom 7:10 - θάνατος (thanatos) = "death" a noun

Let me discuss these one at a time.
νεκρός (nekros) = "dead, lifeless" an adjective
In the NT, this word is used literally of physical death (eg, Acts 28:6, 5:10, James 2:26a, Rev 1:17, Matt 28:4, Luke 7:15, etc), and, in a metaphoric/spiritual sense.
In this latter metaphoric/spiritual sense, there are two sub-meanings:

spiritually dead persons, eg, Luke 15:24, 32, Rom 6:11, 13, Eph 2:1, Col 2:13, Rev 3:1, etc
dead things such as dead works that cannot bring eternal life, Rom 7:8, 8:10, Heb 6;1, 9:14, James 2:26b, etc.

ἀποθνῄσκω (apothnéskó) = "I died" a verb
Again, this verb is used in both a literal sense of physically dying (Matt 9:24, 22:24, 27, Mark 5:35, 39, 9:26, etc), and, in a metaphoric/spiritual sense, eg, Rom 7:9, 10, 8:13, Rev 3:2, John 6:50, 58, 8:21, 24, 11:26, etc
θάνατος (thanatos) = "death" a noun
The various meanings that this common word can take, again, can be classified in those that are of literal physical death (John 11:4, 13, Heb 7:23, 9:15, etc), and, in a metaphoric/spiritual sense, eg, John 7:51, 5:24, 1 John 3:14, Rom 7:10, 13b, 8:6, James 1:15, 5:20, etc.
Thus, while different words and parts of speech are used, the metaphoric/spiritual sense of the words are intended in each case.  That is, when a person is "spiritually dead", they are (BDAG) "morally or spiritually deficient".
The other side of this coin is equally valid - it is possible to be so enlivened by the Spirit that one can be "dead to sin", ie, immune to the milieu of sin around us as Paul states:

Rom 6:10, 11 - The death He died, He died to sin once for all; but the
life He lives, He lives to God. So you too must count yourselves dead
to sin, but alive to God in Christ Jesus.

In Rom 7, Paul discusses the opposite effect - when sinners realis their great need of Christ and their complete dependance on Jesus and the Holy Spirit for all things eternal, they realize that the sinful life they once led was a spiritual sham and thus, died:

Rom 7:9-12 - Once I was alive apart from the law; but when the
commandment came, sin sprang to life and I died. So I discovered that
the very commandment that was meant to bring life actually brought
death. For sin, seizing its opportunity through the commandment,
deceived me and through the commandment put me to death. So then, the
law is holy, and the commandment is holy, righteous, and good.

Paul continues in the next verses:

Rom 7:13, 14 - Did that which is good, then, become death to me?
Certainly not! But in order that sin might be exposed as sin, it
produced death in me through what was good, so that through the
commandment sin might become utterly sinful. We know that the law is
spiritual; but I am unspiritual, sold as a slave to sin.

In commenting on Rom 7:9-11 Benson observes:

Romans 7:9-11. For I was alive — In my own conceit; without the
law — Without the proper knowledge of its spirituality, extent, and
obligation. I apprehended myself to be righteous, and in the way to
life eternal; but when the commandment came — That is, the law; (a
part being put for the whole;) but this expression particularly
intimates its compulsive force, which restrains, enjoins, urges,
forbids, threatens; — when, in its spiritual meaning, it came to my
heart: or, when the spiritual meaning and full extent of the law,
condemning desires of evil, was brought home, and closely applied to
my conscience by the Spirit of God; sin revived — My conscience was
awakened and convinced, and I found myself guilty of many sins, which
before I perceived not, and a lively sense of the guilt of them was
imprinted on my soul; and I died — My virtue and strength died away,
and my former persuasions vanished: for I saw myself to be dead in
sin, in a state of condemnation, and liable to death eternal.


Paul's Use of "Dead" in Ephesians 2:1, Romans 6:11, and Romans 7:9: Does Spiritual Death Imply Total Incapacitation or Inability to Respond to God?
In Romans 6:11 and Ephesians 2:1, Paul describes humanity as "νεκρός" (dead) in transgressions and sins. In Romans 7:9, Paul shares his own experience, stating that he "died" (ἀπέθανον) in sins. These passages raise a key theological and exegetical question:
Does "νεκρός" (dead) paired with "ἀποθνῄσκω" (to die) imply total spiritual incapacitation, requiring resuscitation before responding to the gospel? Or does it suggest a state of spiritual dormancy—like a sleeping giant—where the spirit, though disconnected from God, is still capable of responding to a divine wake-up call?
Understanding the Terms in Biblical Context
It is essential to understand biblical terms within their scriptural context, rather than relying solely on lexical definitions. For example, the first use of the word מוּת (muth – "to die") occurs in Genesis 2:17, when God tells Adam, "When you eat from it, you will surely die" (מוּת). This "death" did not result in Adam’s immediate physical demise but instead signified a relational separation from God, rather than total incapacitation. Adam lived for 930 years after the Fall, along with his descendants, outside the Garden of Eden. While he was barred from access to the Garden and direct communion with God, God still engaged with him as He willed, showing that Adam's death was not complete annihilation but rather separation from God's intimate fellowship.
This understanding sets the interpretive guideline for the term "death" in this context—not as total incapacitation but as separation from God. This approach is crucial for grasping the spiritual deadness of humanity and the power of sin over human spirituality. It also underscores the importance of avoiding interpretations based on any particular theological framework.
"Dead in Sin" Denotes Spiritual Dormancy, Not Total Death
Paul’s statement in Ephesians 2:1, often translated as "dead in sin", carries significant theological, semantic, and exegetical weight. In this context, "dead" refers to being immersed in transgressions and sins, which implies that the person is under sin's influence and spiritually estranged from God. This state describes spiritual dormancy—a condition where individuals cannot respond to God on their own but are still capable of being awakened by God's initiative through His life-giving word.
The Bible indicates that the human spirit never truly dies. Therefore, being "dead in sin" refers to a state of spiritual dormancy, where the spirit is estranged from God but still capable of being awakened by God's intervention. This concept is supported by various biblical examples.
For instance, when Jesus referred to Lazarus' death (ἀποθνῄσκω), He described it as "fallen asleep" (κοιμάομαι), signaling that He would wake (ἐξυπνίζω) him. Lazarus responded and walked out of the tomb when Jesus called him with a loud voice. Similarly, Paul, then known as Saul, though spiritually dead, responded immediately when Jesus called him, saying, "Saul, Saul," on the road to Damascus. Moreover, figures like Adam, Eve, Cain, Abel, and patriarchs such as Noah and Abraham continued to communicate with God even after the Fall, despite living in sin.
These examples suggest that being spiritually "dead" means being dormant—still capable of responding to God's life-giving word, like a sleeping giant. Though estranged from God, the human spirit retains the capacity to awaken and respond to God's call.
Spiritual Dormancy and the Depth of Sin
Spiritual dormancy is not a static condition; it intensifies based on a person's level of sinfulness. For example, Paul, despite his zeal for God, was in one of the deepest stages of spiritual dormancy due to his hostility toward the "new way" of Jesus, as he led the persecution of believers. This state of spiritual near-deadness is not unique to Paul but is seen throughout Scripture.
As Genesis 6:5 reveals, spiritual dormancy deepens as sin increases: "The wickedness of man was great on the earth, and every intention of the thoughts of his heart was only evil continually." As humanity's sinful state worsens, the extent of their spiritual blindness and alienation from God increases proportionally.
Thus, the more pervasive sin becomes, the more profound the state of spiritual dormancy and the harder it becomes for individuals to awaken. Without a timely response to the gospel call—"Repent, believe in the gospel, for the kingdom of Heaven is near"—spiritual νεκρός (spiritually lifeless) becomes the final state.
Doctrinal Considerations: Spiritual Dormancy vs. Total Depravity
Understanding "dead in sin" as a state of spiritual dormancy, rather than total incapacitation, is critical for grasping both the spiritual state of humanity and the transformative power of God's grace. This perspective suggests that the human spirit, though estranged from God, can still be awakened by the gospel call and brought back to spiritual life. It challenges the idea that prior regenerative work by the Holy Spirit is necessary for someone to hear the gospel and respond.
By interpreting "dead in sin" as spiritual dormancy, we avoid theological pitfalls that present humanity’s spiritual state as one of total incapacitation. This understanding emphasizes that sin affects humanity deeply but does not render individuals entirely incapable of responding to God's call.
The Challenge to Total Depravity
The doctrine of total depravity holds that, because of the Fall, every aspect of human nature is corrupted by sin, rendering people entirely unable to seek God or exercise faith on their own without prior divine intervention. This view asserts that regeneration must precede any human response to the gospel.
However, the concept of spiritual dormancy, as discussed above, offers a more balanced Scriptural understanding and challenges this idea. It suggests that humans, though estranged from God, are still capable of responding to the gospel without the need for prior regeneration. This interpretation maintains that even in their fallen state, humans can turn to God when called by Him.
Conclusion
The concept of spiritual dormancy is a crucial interpretive key to understanding Paul's message. The Bible consistently demonstrates that the human spirit, though estranged from God, can still be awakened by the gospel call and brought back to spiritual life, even without prior regenerative work by the Holy Spirit.
In this regard, doctrinal arguments like "A dead man, baby, or creature cannot exercise faith in Jesus Christ," and quoting "The dead know nothing" (Ecclesiastes 9:5) as evidence for spiritual incapacity, are unscriptural attempts at best. Paul exhorts believers, who were once dead in sin but are now alive in Christ, to avoid falling back into living in sin and to set their minds on things above (Romans 6:2 and Colossians 3:3).
Paul clarifies this further in Romans 1:18-21: “For the wrath of God is revealed from heaven against all ungodliness and unrighteousness of people who suppress the truth by their unrighteousness, because what can be known about God is plain to them, because God has made it plain to them... So people are without excuse.”
PS: Romans 1:18-21 affirms that humanity, though spiritually dormant, remains capable of perceiving God through creation and is responsible for suppressing the truth about Him. This further supports the argument that spiritual dormancy does not equate to total incapacitation, and individuals are still capable of responding to God's gospel call.
